# Which version of Xposed should I use for Nexus 5X?

Tags: xposed-framework, arm-processors, nexus-5x

Xposed have 3 different versions: arm, arm64 and x86

Which one should I use for Nexus 5X?

Comment: Not a problem. You can try to flash any Xposed installer you want. The flash script in Xposed installer checks *et al* these build properties: `ro.product.cpu.abi`, `ro.product.cpu.abi2`, `ro.build.version.sdk`. There are checks here and there for platform and the installer would fail if the installer is not meant for the installed Android and device's  architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LG Nexus 5X is the first device with Android 6.0(.1) so it's running SDK23.
X86 is only for x86 processors, which except for the ASUS Zenfone, no one is using.
ARM is for usual 32-bit ARM processors (and 32-bit ROMs). This was the standard about 1/2 to 1 year ago.
ARM64 is the newest generation of 64-bit ARM processors and ROMs supporting this architecture. I suspect your phone is 64-bit capable (at least the processor is).

1. Head over to the official Xposed thread on XDA:
   http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811
2. Download the appropriate Xposed version (xposed-vxx-sdk23-arm64.zip)
3. Copy it to your device.
4. Flash it using a custom recovery.

Comment: So taking this into account: `Kernel Architecture: armv8l`
Should I use ARM and not ARM64?

Comment: I'd say try ARM first. If it works, good; if not, try ARM64. Always take a backup before messing with the system.

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.arm.com/products/processors/armv8-architecture.php

`The ARMv8 architecture introduces 64-bit support to the ARM architecture with a focus on power-efficient implementation while maintaining compatibility with existing 32-bit software.`

Comment: Given that your device supports 64-bit, I assumed the ROM to do so as well. Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33752302/4867727) to a similar problem and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom ROM please define it. And if you are using stock ROM you probably have ARM. Or just download cpu-z from play store and find it there.

Hope that was helpful, Nik

Comment: I am using the stock ROM, rooted.

Comment: OK, so you have android 6.0 installed on Nexus 5X ( the newest update ) ?

Comment: Yep I have Android 6.0.1, Build: MMB29K

Comment: You probably have ARM not ARM64. Besides I think you shouldnt install xposed framework on 6.0 canuse it will make it quite unstable.

Comment: It says armv8 inside CPU-Z, so i am not sure which one to use..

Comment: Look at `System->Kernel Architecture`. If it says `aarch64` it's 64-bit.

Comment: `Kernel Architecture: armv8l`, then I should go for ARM?

Comment: ARM ( 32-bit ). Altrough I dont recommend installing Xposed framework, cause it makes the phone unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Go ARM, not ARM32, so far all the Armv8 phones I have use 32 boot loaders, 32 bit Roms, and etc, a lot of them dont even have the memory to utilize 64, I believe Armv8 is more of a performance tweak, with a future capability to go 64. I could be wrong, but you KNOW Armv7 software will definitely work.